# Asp.net Core 2 Domain dependent View selection?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, multi-tenant

I have a new multi-tenant web application in ASP.NET Core 2.0, single DB.

I've established a method of determining a particular request's 'TenantId' by examining the domain in a simple piece of middleware.

I've also established a DataContext which applies TenantId filters to applicable tables as needed.

The last thing I'm unclear about is how I can differentiate Views/partial views based on the TenantId whilst sharing the controllers.

I think some scheme where the app first looks in some kind of TenantId sub-folder for the customized tenant's view and if it can't find it, it goes through the regular steps to locate the view... might work okay?  Is this a reasonable approach?  In other words, it should use the specialized tenant view if it exists, otherwise use the default view.

Would this involve building a custom view engine of sorts?

I've tried something similar with tenant based Html fragments, but it was a pain maintaining it, so I'm looking for something more straight forward on this project.

I'm open to other suggestions of how to implement this functionality as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a whole custom viewengine, you can implement an IViewLocationExpander to make it check various locations for views.

In my project I have mutliple tenant support with both shared themes and tenant specific themes. I can override any view by dropping a copy below the theme folder, ie the main view could be Views/SiteAdmin/Index and I can override it in /pathtothemes/themefolder/SiteAdmin/Index

You can see [my implementation of IViewLocationExpander here](https://github.com/cloudscribe/cloudscribe/blob/master/src/cloudscribe.Core.Web/Design/SiteViewLocationExpander.cs).

How you register your IViewLocationExpander is like this:

```
services.AddMvc()
            .AddRazorOptions(options =>
            {
                options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new cloudscribe.Core.Web.Components.SiteViewLocationExpander());
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            ;
```

Comment: Perfect! Simpler than I thought!